# trouble with truthy/falsey

Tags: javascript, truthy

A quick intro, I am a total noob learning JS and feel that it's going well, however I am doing a simple exercise right now and I'm hung up on something.

I have learned that:
a falsey value is a value that is considered false when encountered in a boolean context
ex: false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, NaN (Not a number)
truthy is everything other than falsey (such as a String, boolean true, any number not 0 etc.)

so in my example below, if anyone could help me understand why value => value == true, would print out false (as was the case) when I have a string value in my array ("Angela"). Thanks!

```js
let values = [11, NaN, [], "Angela"]

function checkForFalsey() {
  if (values.some(value => value == true)) {
    console.log("At least one item is falsey")
  }
}
checkForFalsey()
```

Comment: `some` will return as soon as the condition is true. It won't reach upto `Angela`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Also note that not all falsy values are considered equal to `false`, even when using sloppy equality (`==`/`!=`)

Comment: You ask "in my example below, if anyone could help me understand why value => value == true, would print out false" but your example shows `value => value == false`. So... what is your question?

Comment: Interesting, but then since my first value in the array is an integer why would I still get a false value?

Comment: Because truthy and true or false are not the same. The number is not == false so will immediately return. Do some more reading on how to test truthy/falsy

Comment: Because, even though the array contains falsy elements, it does not contain any elements for which `element == false` is truthy

Comment: Nothing in your code "prints out false". Please provide code that exactly reproduces the result you are finding confusing.

Comment: Charlietfl's answer makes the most sense. I think I got it. Thanks

Comment: Heretic Monkey -  I edited my code, now it says true. Hope it makes more sense now, I wanted to know why it printed false when I thought a 11, or Angela would be a truthy value and so I was confused why I saw false printed out. But, like I said I think I got it now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit:

The question was a bit confusing because of the snippet, I understood that you were trying to look for falsy values.

The reason why:

```
value => value == true
```

would print out false it's because none of the elements of the array is equal to `true`.

You are correct about what a falsy value is, but that doesn't mean that a truthy value would be `==` to `true`.

Here you can read more about it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

One way of checking for truthy values would be:

```
(values.some(value => value != false))
```

or

```
(values.some(value => !!value === true))
```

Old answer:

Because the method you use tests that at least one element in the array matches the condition.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If you want to check that all elements of the array matches the condition, then you can use `.every()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

```js
let values = [11, NaN, [], ""]

function checkForFalsey() {
  if (values.every(value => value == false)) {
    console.log("All values are falsey");
  } else {
    console.log("NOT all values are falsey");
  }
}
checkForFalsey()
```

Comment: The original question is a bit confusing, but this isn't the correct answer as I understand it. If OP uses `value == true` for the `some(...)` condition, the result is still false and they want to know why.

Comment: Thanks! I missunderstood the question because of the snippet. So I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A string is neither truthy nor falsy. What's happening is called type coercion. Since string and Boolean are not the same type, JavaScript coerces one of the types to match the other then checks equality (a high level explanation). See here for a detailed explanation: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

So when you do `"abc" == true` JavaScript is coercing both values to a number type. A string is not a number, so `toNumber("abc")` returns `NaN`. It also coerces `true` to a number, which returns `1` in this case (1 is true, 0 is false, as you mentioned).

For what it's worth, `NaN` is also not truthy or falsy. Comparing it to true or false will always result in `false`.

Comment: Added detail: `NaN` is not equal to anthing, not even itself: `NaN==NaN` and `NaN===NaN` are both  false.